# Track number of copies made from a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet template that users will be making copies of.  I want to track how many copies have been made.  It would be great if I can actually get a link to every copy that is made.

Is there any way to do this via App Scripts?

Answer (score 0):

I use a modified version of the code below to make and track copies all the time.

There's menu item they can use to copy the spreadsheet.
That code pastes the new spreadsheet's URL in your own tracking sheet.
Although, there's no guarantee that they'll use that method even if you tell them to. Users almost never do it the way you want.

Use a formula in the sheet to count the number of URLs to get the number of copies.

For the code below to work, you will need to install a trigger for the `open` function triggered `On open`. The user will have to grant the script access the first time they use it.

You could also include a change of ownership if you wanted full control over all sheets.

```
function open() {

    SpreadsheetApp
        .getUi()
        .createMenu('Your-menu-name')
        .addItem('Make a copy', 'copy')
        .addToUi();
}

function copy() {

    var tracker = SpreadsheetApp.openById('tracker-id-here');
    var template = DriveApp.getFileById('template-id-here');

    var folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
    //their root folder

    //var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folder-id');
    //use the above line instead if you want to create them in specific folders

    var filename = template.getName();

    var newFile = template.makeCopy(filename, folder);

    var url = newFile.getUrl();

    //newFile.setOwner('email-address-here');
    //use the line above if you want to set an owner who is not the user

    tracker.getSheetByName('your-sheet-name').appendRow([filename, url]);
}
```