# Recording any copies made of a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to create a Google sheet that records any copies that have been made of another Google Sheet even when the user creates a copy by putting 'copy' into the URL (`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"spreadsheet-ID"/copy`).

I have found a solution on the post: [Track number of copies made from a google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53770174/track-number-of-copies-made-from-a-google-spreadsheet) but this doesn't record copies made when changing the URL as the above example.

I would like to know the whole URL of the sheet preferably but just the Spreadhseet ID would still be enough for me.

Has anyone got any ideas how I can record all this data onto a spreadsheet please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you won't have access to see who is copying your sheet if you use the built-in *Make Copy*.

What you could do is integrate part of [the question you have provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53770174/track-number-of-copies-made-from-a-google-spreadsheet), while disabling the [built-in sharing method](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en&visit_id=1-636588785709077336-3170658176&rd=1). So the only way to copy your sheet could be through a custom function you can control and register every time it executes.